Vue text interpolation watches all elements?
Consider the following simple example.
Two counters are rendering, once with ref that gets updated every second and one static:
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { ref } from 'vue'

let staticNumber = 0;
const dynamicNumber = ref(0);

onMounted(() => {
  setInterval(() => dynamicNumber.value++, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => staticNumber = 10);
});
</script>

<template>
  <h1>This should update every second {{ dynamicNumber }}</h1>
  <h1>This should not update at all! {{ staticNumber }}</h1>
</template>

The problem is, after one second pass, the second h1 tag which initially was 0 gets updated and showing 10.
Why? Why Vue is even checking non-ref value and updates them?
I am concerned because on my site I want to support multiple languages so basically the template would look like this:
<template>
  <h1>{{ phrase.greetings }}</h1> <!-- Should be static -->
  <p>{{ phrase.x_visitors(numberOfVisitors) }}</p> <!-- Should be updating -->
  <p>{{ phrase.site_description }}</p> <!-- Should be static -->
</template>

But with the behaviour I metioned above it means every time I update numberOfVisitors variable it will also update all the other elements with text interpolation on the whole site!
Does this mean it will lag and freeze every time something updates?

Can you you explain further what's the concern? It's not "checking" a value, but since you updated it, it will be updated in a view, because you triggered an update with dynamicNumber. And this happened because you use "script setup", which I don't recommend, it works in unobvious and undocumented ways. It adds staticNumber property to internal instance, which isn't the same as you'd expect from similarly written setup function like let staticNumber = 0; ... return { staticNumber }. Basically if you don't want something to be updated, don't update it. This won't happen with phrase.greetings

If phrase.greetings value stays the same, <h1>{{ phrase.greetings }}</h1> DOM element won't be rerendered, that's how VDOM works

Vue doesn't diff VNodes based on whether the data in it is reactive or not, just whether the data is considered dynamic (which text interpolation is). Updates to reactive data triggers a diff/rerender of these nodes. Therefore an update to just staticNumber does not trigger a rerender but it will still be rerendered once other reactive data (like dynamicNumber) is changed. With script setup, all top-level variables are available in the template, which is how the value is available to be updated in the first place, so if you didn't want this, use setup() function where you have more control

I probably misspoke on a few finer details.  this page in the documentation should be read which explains more in depth.
